# Is it possible to bake only shader normals and not geometry normal?

Tags: shaders, texture-baking, baking, shader-nodes

I want to bake only shader normals from principled BSDF and ignore the geometry normals.

I know Blender will bake shader normals and geometry/object normals combined.

When I bake high to low, I want just the shader normal and not the geometry normal.

[image]

I don't want the bevel which comes from the geometry of high poly.

[image]

Any solution to this?

Comment: Hello, have you tried outputing it as an emission shader and baking it as an emission map ?

Comment: What do you mean? I updated my question.